# Star Models, Cube and dimensions in Pentaho 5.4

Tags: pentaho, mondrian

Can someone help me how to do star models, build a cube and dimensions in Pentaho?

Need I install some plugins?

I am looking for tutorials, but the are a lot to pentaho 4.. than don't explain about plugins or ..to Pentaho 5.

Good tutorials are a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use Pentaho Schema Workbench. It will exactly do what you want. Refer this [documentation](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.3/0N0/020/070) they have provided for version 5.4. No need of any plugins if you use this.